# Overflow Exception Error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

This Is In an asp.net Application

i am having this exception 
`System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow`.
but the weird thing is that when the function is called and the result is returned this error seems to surface 
but if i write the function code directly not through a function just write it down beneath the code it will not make this error
kindly help 
here is the code

```
Dim MyItem As New Item    
If MyItem.GetQtyInBin(bran_code.Text, itcode.Text, binloc.Text) <= 0 Then

    ...............

    Exit Sub
```

---

here is the method's code

```
'this method gets the qty of a certain item in a certainn location and returns it
 Public Function GetQtyInBin(ByVal Branch As String, ByVal Item As Integer, ByVal Bin As String) As Integer

    cn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=msdaora; Data Source=llmw; User Id=xxxx;Password=xxxx")
    cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("select Qty from Binprmast where Bin_No='" & Bin & "' and item_Code='" & Item & "' and Bran_Code='" & Branch & "'", cn)
    cn.Open()
    Dim qty As Double
    qty = cmd.ExecuteScalar
    Return qty

End Function
```

---

Comment: Please rename the title of this post. It is vague and unhelpful.

Comment: @JacobSwartwood - I have edited the question title to make it more meaningful

Answer (score 0):

In you question, `GetQtyInBin` is defined to return an `Integer` but the return value `qty` is defined as  a  `Double`.

Double is larger than an Integer, hence the overflow.

Correct like this

```
Public Function GetQtyInBin(ByVal Branch As String, ByVal Item As Integer, ByVal Bin As String) As Double
        cn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=msdaora; Data Source=llmw; User Id=boss;Password=boss")
        cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("select Qty from Binprmast where Bin_No='" & Bin & "' and item_Code='" & Item & "' and Bran_Code='" & Branch & "'", cn)
        cn.Open()
        Dim qty As Double
        qty = cmd.ExecuteScalar
        Return qty
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns an integer but you are setting the return value to be a Double. You need to change one or the other to match.

Note: If you [switch Option Strict On](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) this will not compile as is and will therefore alert you to this error.

Comment: Hey Matt thanks for the quick reply but i have changed it to double  thinking it will solve the problem although the qty returned does not exceed the hundred it was integer before. same issue